# TCP Packet Checksum

Tags: c++, sockets, tcp

i have no idea on how to do this, i have a game and i want to create a checksum on packets, so if a cheater want to alter packets i will reject him.

I have this so far:

```
bool Checksum(unsigned char *buf)
{
    int checksum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(buf); i++)
    {
    checksum += sizeof(buf[i]);
    }
    if (buf[2] == checksum)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

*buf[2] is always the size stored in every packet that is being sent;*

so i tried like this:

```
// receive function here
if (!Checksum(buf) == true)
    {

        printf("[CHECKSUM]: error");

    }
// return the buf
```

But i get always the same message, some help please? Many thanks.

Comment: You are including the calculated checksum in the bytes being accumulated for the checksum - so the checksum is "wrong" as soon as you insert the checksum byte.

Comment: @Richard Critten -  thank you, and how do i do that?

Comment: Umm... don't sum the checksum.